# NullpointerException with context

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, android-context

I am trying to get Shared Preferences in an AsyncTask, but I don't get it.

How do I have to use context here?

```
package com.example.wettkampftimerbt;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class network extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {

    private final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs", W1 = "w1",  W2="w2", W3="w3", W4="w4", 
            W5="w5", W6="w6", W7="w7", SENDBEG="sendbeg", SENDEND="sendend";
    int w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, sendend, sendbeg;

    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
        int c2, c3, c4, c5, c6;
        int w0 = 00;
        try {
            w1 = sendbeg;
            c2 = w2;
            c3 = w3;
            c4 = w4;
            c5 = w5;
            c6 = w6;
            w7 = sendend;

            Socket ss = new Socket("192.168.3.100", 4455);
            System.out.println(ss);
            boolean stopData = true;
            System.out.println("lane1 stop send");
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                    ss.getOutputStream());
            while (stopData) {
                dos.writeByte(w0);
                dos.writeByte(w1);
                dos.writeByte(c2);
                dos.writeByte(c3);
                dos.writeByte(c4);
                dos.writeByte(c5);
                dos.writeByte(c6);
                dos.writeByte(w7);
                stopData=false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Done";
    }

    public void onPreExecute(){
        Context context = network.this;
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME");

        doInBackground();
    }

    public void getPrefs (Context context){         
        w1= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W1, "00"));
        w2= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W2, "00"));
        w3= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W3, "00"));
        w4= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W4, "00"));
        w5= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W5, "00"));
        w6= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W6, "00"));
        w7= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W7, "00"));
        sendbeg= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SENDBEG, "00"));
        sendend= Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SENDEND, "00"));
    }
}
```

This is the snippet, my problem is about: I have no errors, except to a **nullPointerException** (caused by `getPrefs(null);`?) on Start. Can someone help me?

I already read a lot of context explanations and even the Android developer site I visited, but I don't get, WHAT context is, and what it exactly does.

EDIT: Thanks for the fast answers, but it still does not work. I put now the whole activity in here, with one sample you gave me, but I get errors now. Is it up to me, or does Eclipse hate me?

EDIT2: I call the doInBackground on my own, because it does not start on HIS own.

EDIT3: Worked around now, it works ^^ I am calling getPrefs from my main activity directly, and then network from getPrefs... fine so far, but: I'm getting this NetworkOnMainThreadException error.  What to do now?

Comment: `getPrefs(null);` ??????????? (yes, that's a lot of ?, but i am really puzzled)

Comment: thats what eclipsed said me with ctrl+1 oo

Comment: and you don't think that could cause, say, a nullpointerexception when you try to access it ?

Comment: thats what i think... because of that i specifically mentioned it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Define a local variable in your Async class(in your case which is network class)

```
Context context;
```

2) Create constructor in your Async Task to accept context:

```
public network(Context context) {
    this.context = context;       
}
```

3) Now, in `onPreExecute()` while calling `getPrefs`, call like this :

```
getPrefs(context);
```

4) You can call this class from your MainActivity like this:

```
network networkObj= new network(MainActivity.this);
networkObj.execute(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to give the context of your class to the `getPrefs()`. 
use `getPrefs(yourActivity.this)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

**1. Define your AsyncTask as an inner class of your Activity**
Your AsyncTask class **must not** be static for this to work.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...    

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ...

        public void onPreExecute() {
            Context context = MyActivity.this;
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME");
        }
    }

}
```

**2. Pass your Activity/context to your AsyncTask constructor and maintain a WeakReference to it**
Your AsyncTask class should be static. Do not just maintain a hard reference to your Activity/context (unless it is the Application context) otherwise you **will** leak memory:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private WeakReference<Context> mContextRef;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
        mContextRef = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }

    ...

    public void onPreExecute() {
        Context context = mContextRef.get();
        // context may be null if the activity has been destroyed
        if (context != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME");
        }
    }
}
```